# How to implement a check-in test for omni completion script?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system

I've been working in an omni-completion script for Vim that is becoming more and more complex. At this point I'm interested in implementing some kind of check-in regression test for the script.

Any ideas on how to implement such a test?

Note: github + travis-ci solution is preferred.